# Grouping labels when x is a factor variable in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to replace the x-axis labels "A0" and "A1" by one "A" which can be placed in the middle of "A0" and "A1". It would be better if there is a method which works like the following question:
[grouping of axis labels ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277292/grouping-of-axis-labels-ggplot2)

By that, I mean to redraw the x-axis only for each group, and leave a blank between groups.

Here is the code I'm working on:

```
y = 1*round(runif(20)*10,1)
x1 = c("A","B")
x2 = c(0,1)
x = expand.grid(x1,x2)
xy = cbind(x,y)
xy$z = paste(xy$Var1,xy$Var2,sep="")

p <- ggplot(xy, aes(x=factor(z), y=y,fill=factor(Var2)))
p + geom_boxplot() + geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=.2)) + theme_bw() + xlab("X") + ylab("Y") + scale_fill_discrete(name="Var2",breaks=c(0, 1),labels=c("T", "C"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. No need for the variable `z`, just use `position="dodge"`:

```
p <- ggplot(xy, aes(x=factor(Var1), y=y,fill=factor(Var2)))
p + geom_boxplot(position="dodge") + geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=.2)) + theme_bw() + xlab("X") + ylab("Y") + scale_fill_discrete(name="Var2",breaks=c(0, 1),labels=c("T", "C"))
```